# Dynamic JS route in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to include different js file, depending on environment. I've tried:

```
{% javascripts
    'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
    'bundles/fosjsrouting/' ~ app.environment ~ '/js/fos_js_routes.js'
    filter='?yui_js'
    output='compiled/routing'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
 {% endjavascripts %}
```

But it gives error about unexpected character `~`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible unfortunately at the moment. This is because you can't use variables in Assetic paths.

However, you could use `asset` twig helper:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/' ~ app.environment ~ '/js/fos_js_routes.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I think about it, but here i need to compile this asset, which is not possible in this approach.

Comment: Indeed, and that is exact reason why assetic can't accept variables, because it can't scan templates for assets when they contain variables that could be anything (calculated from controller, request, etc).

Comment: However it seems that they somehow added this feature recently in Assetic 1.1 http://jmsyst.com/blog/asset-variables-in-assetic . You should check which version you're using with your symfony distribution !

Comment: Ok, i've got it. Anyway it seems that it's the only way to do what we need, tnx